# How to switch from camera recording to on screen recording using RecordRTC API?

Tags: recordrtc

I am a newbie to Audio/Video Recording. The script works well for my cam and audio recorder. However, I would like to know how to implement it similar to the Extension available so that I can record a tab and all the audio involved. Thanks in advance. Currently using Ver.5.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Here is an open-sourced chrome-extension that supports both tab, screen and any opened app's screen recording:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/tree/master/screen-recording

You can use `tabCapture` API to capture `MediaStream` object; now you can record the resulting stream using MediaRecorder API or **RecordRTC**.

RecordRTC can record following kind of streams:

1. Stream captured from a webcam or microphone
2. Stream captured using tabCapture API
3. Stream captured using desktopCapture API
4. Stream captured from `<canvas>` or `<video>` elements using `captureStream` API
5. Streams generated by WebAudio API

e.g.

```
var capturedStream = videoElement.captureStream();

var recorder = RecordRTC(videoElement.captureStream(), {
   type: 'video'
});
```

Or:

```
var recorder = RecordRTC(tabCaptureStream, {
   type: 'video'
});
```

Simply make sure that you're getting the `MediaStream` object from above API; and now you can use RecordRTC to record that stream.

Regarding "**replacing video track with secondary camera track or screen track**", you can use `addTrack`, `removeTrack` as well as `replaceTrack` methods. However **I'm not sure** if MediaRecorder API can record replaced track:

```
// using Firefox
theStreamYouAreRecording.replaceTrack( screenTrack );

// using Chrome or Firefox
theStreamYouAreRecording.addTrack ( screenTrack );
```

So you must either record camera or screen. Do not replace tracks.